# Fluent Nhibernate ImportType

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've literally searched high and low, and can't seem to find a recent solution for this.

I'm trying to implement a un-mapped class which is a DTO from 2 tables and will be returned from a HQL statement.

I can't find any examples of how to do this in Fluent Hibernate, only in standard NHibernate XML files which, doesn't suit our needs.

Has anybody had any experience of using  the `<Import class="CLASS" />` in Fluent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently accomplished just what you are asking.  I found the instructions at this URL:

http://avinashsing.sunkur.com/2010/08/18/mapping-an-unrelated-class-in-fluent-nhibernate/

The example in that link don't happen to use two tables in a join, but it works just the same: just use the ImportType<> directive in one of the classes.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the same link I found which sorted out issue.